# How can I display something different in a Spinner than in the drop-down?

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

I have an Android Spinner widget in which I'd like to display a slightly different string for the first item if it's selected vs. if it's being displayed in the drop-down. For example, clicking

```
[Select a dessert...  v]
```

Pops up:

```
o No dessert
  Cake
  Pie
  Ice cream
```

If e.g. "Cake" is chosen, the Spinner behaves normally:

```
[Cake                 v]
```

But if "No dessert" is chosen, `Select a dessert...` should be used as the Spinner prompt, as when nothing was selected.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using an approach similar to the one below, the `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` defaults to the `toString()` value of the object in the adapter. With that in mind, override the `toString()` method of some custom `ListItem` class to return whatever value you want the spinner to display when the item is being shown as a dropdown item. Meanwhile override the getView for the item *selected* in the adaptor.

```
ArrayAdapter<ListItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        final TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        t.setText("Something else");
        return v;
    }
};
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
ddlSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Effective java solution!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set a `android:prompt="Select a dessert..."` inside the `<Spinner>`.